# Asymptotics of a certain trace involving random matrices with general elliptical covariance structure

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, random-matrices, statistical-physics, free-probability

Let $n,d,m$ be large positive integers that the ratios $d/n$ and $d/m$ are fixed in $(0,\infty)$. Let $G \in \mathbb R^{n \times d}$ and $S \in \mathbb R^{d \times m}$ be independent random matrices with iid entries from $N(0,1)$, and set
\begin{align}
T &:= \Sigma^{1/2} S \in \mathbb R^{d \times m},\\
C &:= TT' \in \mathbb R^{d \times d},\\
H &:=G'(GCG' +n\lambda I_n)^{-1}G \in \mathbb R^{d \times d}.
\end{align}

Let $\lambda > 0$ and let $\Sigma \in \mathbb R^{d \times d}$ be a deterministic positive-definite matrix.

**Question.** What are limiting expressions for (the expectations of) the following quantities ?

- $\mathrm{tr}(\Sigma H C)$,
- $\mathrm{tr}(\Sigma H C^2 H')$.

### Notes

- I'm particularly interested in the case $\lambda \to 0^+$. Also, in case it helps, it may be assumed that $\Sigma=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_d)$ where $\lambda_k = k^{-\beta}$ for all $k \in \{1,\ldots,d\}$ and for some fixed $\beta \gt 1$.